# How should I parse this json response in c#?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, json

I'm a bit new to json responses.  I've been using json.net to parse my responses into custom object.  But I get the feeling that this response is a standard format that I should be able to parse easily.

Here a sample of the response.

```
 {"jquery": 
[
    [0, 1, "call", ["body"]], 
    [1, 2, "attr", "find"], 
    [2, 3, "call", [".status"]], 
    [3, 4, "attr", "hide"], 
    [4, 5, "call", []], 
    [5, 6, "attr", "html"], 
    [6, 7, "call", [""]], 
    [7, 8, "attr", "end"], 
    [8, 9, "call", []], 
    [0, 10, "call", ["body"]], 
    [10, 11, "attr", "captcha"], 
    [11, 12, "call", ["uIP22Wow9xa68aLQ0tl1e9Uiiinracdj"]]
]}
```

Is this something standard or should I just go ahead with my custom object?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like a data structure describing a jQuery collection. There really shouldn't be anything "standard" on the .NET side to represent this. What's sending this JSON to you?

Comment: Also, the question is phrased unfortunately. You should parse this data in a way that's appropriate for what you're ultimately doing with it, except you haven't said what that is.

Comment: I just want to access the last value, which I already have a method to do that, I just can't shake the feeling that there's a better way to do it.

Comment: The best way to do X is the one that's straightforward and works. It'd be overkill to introduce a library to parse whatever format that is just to read a captcha value. (And ideally, you should only send `{"captcha":"..."}` to the server to begin with instead of however you've come to the structure above.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET 4.5 includes a [JavaScriptSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) which makes it easy to parse just about anything.

I usually parse my data doing something like this..

```
private struct MyStruct
{
  public System.Collections.ArrayList jquery { get; set; }
}

string testJson = "{\"jquery\": [[0, 1, \"call\", [\"body\"]], [1, 2, \"attr\", \"find\"], [2, 3, \"call\", [\".status\"]], [3, 4, \"attr\", \"hide\"], [4, 5, \"call\", []], [5, 6, \"attr\", \"html\"], [6, 7, \"call\", [\"\"]], [7, 8, \"attr\", \"end\"], [8, 9, \"call\", []], [0, 10, \"call\", [\"body\"]], [10, 11, \"attr\", \"captcha\"], [11, 12, \"call\", [\"uIP22Wow9xa68aLQ0tl1e9Uiiinracdj\"]]]}";
MyStruct generic = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<MyStruct>(testJson);
```

[image]

Comment: You may want do not use not type safe ArrayList.

Comment: Darn, that class isn't available in WinRT.  Looks like I'll have to create an object for it.  Thanks anyway, this was the exact solution I was looking for.

Comment: I was just trying to show the OP that he could deserialize his data into a custom object. The arraylist was just for a quick example.

Answer (score 0):

This is well-formed JSON, with one object named `"jquery"`. Its value is an array, each element of that array is an array again. The inner array contains several values: two numbers, then a string and lastly a string or an array of a single string.

There is nothing to suggest if any other object named `"jquery"` would have the same structure.

A generic JsonObject seems to be the only useful structure to parse this, in absence of any additional schema information